# Turn the flag on when the digits shows twice in a number - C

Tags: c, for-loop, digits

Without using an array.. How can I manage to turn a flag from 1 to 0 if there is the same digit twice or more in a number?

**take it as if they are all integers, the temp & temp2 are the same number which is a 4 digit number**

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) //if a digits shows twice
{
    n = temp % 10;
    for(k = 0; k <= 6; k++)
    {
        if(n == temp2 % 10)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        temp2 /= 10;
    }
    temp /= 10;
    if(counter > 1)
    {
        flag = 0;
    }
    counter = 0;
}
```

The result is that just it doesn't work.. something is not working

Comment: Very unclear what your code tries to do... or how it fails ... or what you found debugging it. Why would not you just count how often each digit shows up by building frequncy table of 10 elements and then check if you got anything above 1 in the table?

Comment: PLease elaborate "it doesn't work". Give examples of input and output.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov No arrays.

Comment: Please demonstrate the failure with a [mcve] an (un-)suitable input.

Comment: @Yunnosch  Would you think using bit flags for counter work for OP?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Bitflags would probably mean bending the no-array rule. I would not dare handing that in.

Comment: More trolling (since @Yunnosch is probably right that bit flags would cheat on "no array" rule): I think recursion would actually be easier to write for code you are trying: `last_digit_repeated(n) { /*check if last digit repeated*/ || last_digit_repeated(n/10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You take the least significant digit and check if it is present in the rest of the number. If it is found, you're done. If it is not found, you divide the number by 10 and repeat the process. Example:

```
 n = 123456789;
 step 1: Is 9 present in 12345678
 step 2: Is 8 present in 1234567
 step 3: Is 7 present in 123456
 .. and so on ..
```

So first you write a function that can tell whether a number contains a specific digit. The function could look like:

```
int contains_digit(int number, int digit)
{
  while(number)
  {
    if ((number % 10) == digit) return 0;  // Return zero when found
    number /= 10;
  }
  return 1; // Return one if not found
}
```

Then you call that function for all digits in the original number and tests the digit to the number divided by 10. For instance if the number is 1234, you call the function like:

```
contains_digit(123, 4)
contains_digit(12, 3)
contains_digit(1, 2)
```

That can be something like:

```
int main( void )
{
  int n = 12434;
  int flag = 1;
  while(n && flag)
  {
    flag = contains_digit(n/10, n % 10);
    n /= 10;
  }

  printf("flag is %d\n", flag);
  return 0;
}
```